# Creating a simple graph using pandas and Networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to figure out from the documentation how to create a simple graph using the pandas dataframe and the NetworkX package, but I couldn't get the solution. Below the final result I would like.

[image: Desired solution]

Comment: Give more information about data you have in your DataFrame please

Comment: What is contained in your data frame and what from your image you want to have in the graph? I guess you want to have directed, weighted edges? Do you also want to have the color encoded in your graph via node attributes?

Comment: Hi I assume I have this dataframe: df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C'], 'to': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'D'], 'weight': [10, 5, 4, 1]}). From the graph I would like the directed and weighed edges with the weight label on top of the arrow, as well as the colored nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"from": ["A", "A", "A", "C"], "to": ["B", "C", "D", "D"], "weight": [10, 5, 4, 1]}
)


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df, source="from", target="to", edge_attr=["weight"], create_using=nx.DiGraph
)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # node positions

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight") # labels to use for edges

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `pos` to the first `draw` call.

Comment: Thank you @PaulBrodersen it is very useful, is there also a way to change the thickness of the arrow based on the value of the "weight" and the color of the nodes?